# Conditionally replace urls in entire HTML document (inc header)

Tags: regex, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm looking for a way to update local file references in a HTML document.

The replacement will need to be fairly flexible as the URL could be long or short and may or may not be contained in quotes. The main constant is they will all be wrapped in a url() tag. Some examples are:

```
url(images/image1.jpg)
url('images/temp/image1.gif')
url('/temp/image1.png')
url(files/folder1/temp/filename.xls)
```

Any URLs starting with http, https or www should be excluded from the replacement.

For each match that is found I need to extract the filename and replace the rest of the URL with a fixed URL. e.g. (based on the examples above)

```
url(MyNewDirectory/image1.jpg)
url('MyNewDirectory/image1.gif')
url('MyNewDirectory/image1.png')
url(MyNewDirectory/filename.xls)
```

This is to be used in a vb.net project where I am using HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) to perform other replacements. I don't believe it's possible to use HAP to achieve the above as the file references will mostly appear in the HTML header or as inline styles. I'm hoping it will be possible either via regex or some cunning vb.net string manipulation.

Here's a very basic example document showing some of the ways the file references may appear. The images could be in a root directory or 20 directories deep.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Image Replacement</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .myclass[id=mobile] { display:block;  background-image: url(images/hero-mobile.jpg) !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-position: center !important;}
    .myclass2 { background:url(https://google.com/images/hello.jpg) no-repeat !important; } 
  </style>
  </head>
  <body topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bgcolor="#f8f7f5" style="background-color:#f8f7f5; background-image: url('/images/directory1/directory2/anotherimage.jpg') ">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#f8f7f5" style="background-color:#f8f7f5; background-image: url(thisimage.jpg)">
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Solution:**

Here's the final code in case anyone else is trying to do the same. This is vb.net with HAP providing the entire HTML content in doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("url\((?:\'|\"")?(?!(?:http|ftp))(?<path>.+)\/(?<filename>.*?)\1?\)")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml)
For Each match As Match In matches
  doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml = Replace(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml, match.Value, "url('/MyNewDirectory/" &  match.Groups("filename").Value & "')")
Next
```

Comment: is this all embedded in CSS, or just plaintext in the html?

Comment: They appear both in the CSS in the header as well as inline CSS in the body of the document. For the sake of argument it would be possible to parse the entire HTML document as plaintext for the purpose of making replacements

Comment: After pulling the path and stripping the single quote, you could use System.IO.Path.GetFileName to pull the filename and append your new path to it.

Comment: Isn't this just simple string replacements?  A bit of `RegEx` and some if blocks...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will capture the part of the url you wanted to replace in the one capturing group.
Only tested with the 4 examples you provided though:

```
url\((?:\'|\")?(.+)\/.*?\1?\)
```

Tested on regex101 and it matched:

```
images
images/temp
/temp
files/folder1/temp
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, I forgot you didn't want to include urls starting with http:

```
url\((?:\'|\")?(?!(?:http|ftp))(.+)\/.*?\1?\)
```

Here you can add anything prefix you want to exclude.

If you want to capture the filename all you need it to put brackets around the part you want to capture:

```
url\((?:\'|\")?(?!(?:http|ftp))(.+)\/(.*?)\1?\)
```

This will give you 2 groups, the first with the part you want to replace and the second with the filename. (The first group is a non capturing group to identify a possible single or double quote, this one will no be available as a captured group, so there will only be 2)

You can also use named groups to keep it more clear:

```
url\((?:\'|\")?(?!(?:http|ftp))(?<path>.+)\/(?<filename>.*?)\1?\)
```

I'm not sure why long url's would get truncated. Could you post an example of a url which gets truncated?

Comment: Thanks, this is a great point in the right direction. I've updated my question to include an example HTML document. The regex you've provided finds all the url() markup but also includes those starting with http* and truncates very long urls for some reason. My regex knowledge is basic but expanding quickly. I hoped I'd be able to get the filename by using match.Groups(3).Value but only group 1 contains a value?

Comment: Thanks! almost there now. The only update I need is for the regex to exclude any URLs that begin with http, https, //, or www. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot about that part. Done now. But not sure why some url's get truncated. Would need an example.

Comment: Perfect. I misunderstood / misused the regex so I thought it was truncating but it wasn't. Thanks very much for your help.